# Mathematica is failing the computation of $\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\cos(k x)\right)\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried to compute

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\cos(k x)\right)\mathrm dx$$

with two different codes:

```
Integrate[Sum[Cos[k*x],{k,0,n}],{x,0,2*Pi},Assumptions->n\[Element]Integers && n>0]
```

and

```
Refine[Integrate[Sum[Cos[k*x],{k,0,n}],{x,0,2*Pi}],n\[Element]Integers && n>0]
```

but both failed. However if I make a table of values for `n` then the computation works normally. There is a way to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integral is so simple and the interchangeability of summation and integration is so obvious to a human but not always to a computer, especially with an undefined symbolic number of summation terms. I hope in future this will just work, but for you to get results try making tiny simple changes that simplify things dramatically.

```
Sum[Integrate[Cos[k*x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}], {k, 0, n}]
```

$2 \pi$

Comment: Yes, it is obvious in this case... but I want to know if I can fix this behavior for other cases.

Comment: @Masacroso Why if interchangeability of summation and integration always works?

Comment: I dont knew that changing the order it can fix this behavior, thank you. Probably what happens is that mathematica dont know that `k` is a natural number for the other computation order.